# Declaring dynamic keys in json (javascript, node)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I have an array of objects, each object is similar to:

```
{ word: 'intentional',
  definition: 'done by intention or design',
  type: 'adjective',
  Synonyms: [  'conscious', 'deliberate', 'intended', 'knowing', ] }
```

I am trying to convert the whole array into following `json` format:

```
{
    "conscious": {
        "data": ["done by intention or design"],
        "type": "adjective",
        "Synonym For": ["intentional"]
    },
    "deliberate": {
        "data": ["done by intention or design"],
        "type": "adjective",
        "Synonym For": ["intentional"]
    },
    ...

}
```

This json format is an input to another program, which I do not control.
I am running it on node.js.

How can I declare an object and then loop through the array to fill it as intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var obj = { word: 'intentional',
  definition: 'done by intention or design',
  type: 'adjective',
  Synonyms: [ 'conscious', 'deliberate', 'intended', 'knowing' ] },
  
  res = obj.Synonyms.reduce(function(s,a) {
    s[a] = { data: [obj.definition], type: obj.type, SynonymFor: [obj.word] };
    return s;
  }, {});
  
  console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var jsonObj = {};
wordArray.forEach((word) => {
    word.Synonyms.forEach((synonym) => {
        jsonObj[synonym] = {
            data: [word.definition],
            type: word.type,
            'Synonym For': [word.word]
        };
    })
})
```

Comment: Why did you move `Synonym For` out of the object literal to its own statement?

Comment: I tought it won't work because of the space inside, but you are right. @zerkms